# Generalized C*- $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, hilbert-spaces

Are there any generalization of $\sigma$-algebra by involving $C^*$ algebra?

For example, loosely speaking, let $\mathcal F$ be a $\sigma$-field, instead of measure $f:\mathcal F\to\mathbb R,$
we have:

$$f:\mathcal F\to\mathcal H,$$ where $\mathcal H$ denotes Hilbert space.

Are there any reference to the properties of
$C^*$-algebra valued measurable functions (with respect to a $\sigma$-algebra)?

---

https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0601158.pdf

---

Best Answer: 
Vector Measure
http://www.diss.fu-berlin.de/diss/servlets/MCRFileNodeServlet/FUDISS_derivate_000000000210/1_kap1.pdf;jsessionid=5C576F6BDE980D3F181901358C3C2C46?hosts=

Some thing related I found.

Integration with Banach valued measure
https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/scripties/BoxtelMaster.pdf

Vector value-measurable function
https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-0346-0211-2_19?no-access=true

other interesting stuff (may be unrelated)

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-0346-0211-2_19?no-access=true
http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/435/1/012004/pdf

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122503/what-is-quantum-brownian-motion
[Can one use complex numbers in probability?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387052/can-one-use-complex-numbers-in-probability)

Comment: A $\sigma$-algebra is a family of sets, not a family of functions. Perhaps you mean $C^*$-algebra valued measurable functions (with respect to a $\sigma$-algebra)?

Comment: @md2perpe Thank you Dr. That is exactly what I am asking.

Comment: I see no problem in having $V$-valued measures for any linear space $V$.

Comment: Are you interested in measures taking values in a $C^*$-algebra or $C^*$-valued measurable functions? For both variants, there are extensive theories if we weaken the $C^*$-algebra to a Banach space (or even less). However, I know of no results using an additional property of $C^*$-algebras to obtain stronger conclusions...the closest thing coming to my mind are spectral measures (sometimes called resolutions of the identity). They are basically measures taking values in the space of orthogonal projections on a Hilbert space but also (extensively) make use of the multiplication structure.

Comment: Do you have anything specific in mind or is your question just motivated by curiosity?

Comment: @haemi It is motivated by curiosity. Are you talking about Banach measure? Could you please provide one or two good lecture notes or textbooks on this topic?

Comment: Curiosity, I like it! In my experience, many people learning mathematics are satisfied by what their lectures present to them...in any case, the correct term for what I meant is "vector measures". As for notes, I have found a short chapter with very few proofs: http://www.diss.fu-berlin.de/diss/servlets/MCRFileNodeServlet/FUDISS_derivate_000000000210/1_kap1.pdf;jsessionid=5C576F6BDE980D3F181901358C3C2C46?hosts= And there is the classic monograph by Diestel and Uhl called simply "vector measures" - I must warn you however, it is quite difficult to read...